# Optimizing mysql IN query having large values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql query like

```
 SELECT `tbl_ticket`.`id`, `tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_username`, 
`tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_email`, `tbl_ticket`.`ticket_title`, 
`tbl_complain_type`.`complains` FROM `tbl_ticket` LEFT JOIN 
`tbl_ticket_complain` ON tbl_ticket_complain.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_complain_type` ON tbl_complain_type.id=tbl_ticket_complain.complain_id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_assignment` ON tbl_assignment.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
WHERE ((((`hd_user_username` LIKE '%searchterm%') 
AND (`tbl_assignment`.`id` IN ($array))) 
OR (`hd_user_email`='searchterm')) 
OR (`ticket_title`='searchterm')) OR (`tbl_complain_type`.`complains`='searchterm')

$array contains around 7000 values like `$array=array(1,2,3,..)`
```

This query takes around 8 seconds  to execute. Is there any alternative solution for this query ?
The value of $array is got from another query

```
select max(id) from tbl_assignment group by ticket_id
```

The slowness of query is due to  multiple joins between tables

Comment: You could load those many values into a table, index the column, and then join to it.

Comment: those values of $array are from another table

Comment: Then consider joining to that table.

Comment: I added that query in my question now

Comment: Explain "too much time". Please read & act on [mcve]. Also this has been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

If the values in the array use in you IN clause come from a select  you could use the fact that
An IN clause is equivalent to an inner join so you could use a inner join between your_table_with_id and the table.column you need for match eg:

```
  SELECT `
      tbl_ticket`.`id`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_username`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_email`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`ticket_title`
      , `tbl_complain_type`.`complains` 
  FROM `tbl_ticket` 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_ticket_complain` ON tbl_ticket_complain.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_complain_type` ON tbl_complain_type.id=tbl_ticket_complain.complain_id 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_assignment` ON tbl_assignment.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
  INNER JOIN your_table_with_id ON `tbl_assignment`.`id` = JOIN your_table_with_id.id
  WHERE ((((`hd_user_username` LIKE '%searchterm%') 
  OR (`hd_user_email`='searchterm')) 
  OR (`ticket_title`='searchterm')) OR (`tbl_complain_type`.`complains`='searchterm')
```

Remeber also that the content of values use IN clause is limited  and fail when the limit is exceeded

and in your case

```
  SELECT `
      tbl_ticket`.`id`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_username`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`hd_user_email`
      , `tbl_ticket`.`ticket_title`
      , `tbl_complain_type`.`complains` 
  FROM `tbl_ticket` 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_ticket_complain` ON tbl_ticket_complain.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_complain_type` ON tbl_complain_type.id=tbl_ticket_complain.complain_id 
  LEFT JOIN `tbl_assignment` ON tbl_assignment.ticket_id=tbl_ticket.id 
  INNER JOIN (
    select max(id) as id
    from tbl_assignment 
    group by ticket_id
  ) t ON `tbl_assignment`.`id` = t.id
  WHERE ((((`hd_user_username` LIKE '%searchterm%') 
  OR (`hd_user_email`='searchterm')) 
  OR (`ticket_title`='searchterm')) OR (`tbl_complain_type`.`complains`='searchterm'))
```

Comment: the IN clause is with this query result "select max(id) from tbl_assignment group by ticket_id"

Comment: it is showing an error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN t.id
  WHERE ((((`hd_user_username` LIKE '%san%') 
  OR (`hd_user_email`=' at line 14

Comment: answer  updated ... a wrong `JOIN `  in on clause remove  .. but seem also  you have a execed ( in where

Comment: still the query is slow. I think it is not with that array, i removed the array join condition, still it is slow

Comment: if is slow  then you should work on proper index .. and the use of the join let you use the index .. the use of In clause  no ..

Comment: Man, some aliases sure would be nice.

Comment: @Strawberry And those backticks aren't the most photogenic things I have seen today either.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically your query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tbl_ticket t LEFT JOIN 
     tbl_ticket_complain tc
     ON tc.ticket_id = t.id LEFT JOIN 
     tbl_complain_type tct
     ON tct.id = tc.complain_id LEFT JOIN
     tbl_assignment a
     ON a.ticket_id = t.id 
WHERE (((hd_user_username LIKE '%searchterm%' AND
         a.id IN ($array)
        ) OR
        `hd_user_email`='searchterm'
       ) OR
       ticket_title = 'searchterm'
     ) OR
     tct.complain` = 'searchterm';
```

The issue with performance has nothing to do with `IN`.  In fact, MySQL optimizes `IN`, as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type
>   of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a
>   binary search. This means `IN` is very quick if the `IN` value list
>   consists entirely of constants.

You are not going to get faster than an `IN` list with constants.

The problem with your query is the string of `OR`s.  These make is almost impossible for the optimizer to use indexes -- so the full result set has to be created and then filtered down.

It is hard for me to see how to improve this in your query.  Sometimes, splitting a query into simpler chunks and connecting them using `union` or `union all` does the trick.  Your conditions are a bit hard to follow, making that approach difficult for an outsider.